# Why gives mysql the error ER_TABLE_NOT_LOCKED while I just locked the table?

Tags: mysql, locking

I have some code that does a LOCK TABLE on a table in my database.

After the lock, I do a SELECT from this same table. My mysql API interface gives the following error:

```
mysqlsel/db server: Table 'Mytable' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

According some googling, this relays to the error code: ER_TABLE_NOT_LOCKED

Why would this code generate this error? I would not expect it to give an error if I do not lock it at all, and I certainly do not expect an error if I lock it either.

Comment: What code are you talking about? I don't see any code in your question.

Comment: The code is a database-abstraction layer and is a bit complex (large) to display here. But there is a function that calls the SQL 'LOCK TABLE' command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved my own question by ['RTM'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/lock-tables.html),

> A session that requires locks must
>   acquire all the locks that it needs in
>   a single `LOCK TABLES` statement. While
>   the locks thus obtained are held, the
>   session can access only the locked
>   tables. For example, in the following
>   sequence of statements, an error
>   occurs for the attempt to access t2
>   because it was not locked in the `LOCK
>   TABLES` statement:

I locked multiple tables in separate lock statements,

So if I do:

```mysql
LOCK TABLES Mytable WRITE
LOCK TABLES Mytable2 WRITE
```

... a subsequent `SELECT FROM Mytable` probably triggers this error...