# Why am I receiving a not locked error?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that get the last value of a barcode and increment it by one. The barcode is prefix by `PU` by the way. Example is `PU1000040` I start the count in `PU1000001`

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        LEFT(BARCODE, 2),
        MAX(
            RIGHT(BARCODE, LENGTH(BARCODE) - 2)* 1
        )+ 1
    )AS newbarcode
FROM
    KGU
WHERE
    HW_TYPE = 'STANDARD PURGE UNIT'
```

This is working fine and always increment it by one so there will never be a duplicate. Then I realize if I put it in my live server where no data still exist it will not return anything because there is nothing to increment it by one. So I made this query:

```
SELECT
    CASE
WHEN EXISTS(
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        KGU
    WHERE
        HW_TYPE = 'STANDARD PURGE UNIT'
)THEN
    (
        SELECT
            CONCAT(
                LEFT(BARCODE, 2),
                MAX(
                    RIGHT(BARCODE, LENGTH(BARCODE) - 2)* 1
                )+ 1
            )
        FROM
            KGU
        WHERE
            HW_TYPE = 'STANDARD PURGE UNIT'
    )
ELSE
    'PU1000001'
END AS newbarcode
```

When I run it in navicat it really does output `PU1000001` when no record exist. And increment the last barcode if there is an existing. However when run in program it cause an error. Specifically in this line: `$new_barcode = $conn_hwcdb->getOne($sql);`

The error I receive says:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DB Error: not locked' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\hwcdb\api\Database.php on line 69

Exception: DB Error: not locked in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\hwcdb\api\Database.php on line 69

```
  function getOne($sql) {
    $result = $this->conn->getOne($sql);

    if(DB::isError($result)) {
      throw new Exception($result->getMessage(), $result->getCode());
    }

    return $result;
  }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473120/why-gives-mysql-the-error-er-table-not-locked-while-i-just-locked-the-table

Comment: That seems to be an issue specific to whatever database library you are using. Can you run other queries?